# A question about maps of spectra

Tags: homotopy-theory

Maybe this is obvious but I can´t figure it out.

Suppose that we have a connective spectrum $X$ and consider a spectrum $Y$. Let $Y^{\prime}\to Y$ be its (-1)-connective cover.

Is it true that $[X,Y]\cong [X,Y^{\prime}]$?

Answer (score 5):

If $X$ has homotopy groups in dimensions above $n-1$, then $\mathrm{Map}(X, Y) = \mathrm{Map}(X, \tau_{\geq n} Y)$ for all $Y$. Similarly, if $Y$ has homotopy groups only up through dimension $n$, then $\mathrm{Map}(X, Y) = \mathrm{Map}(\tau_{\leq n} X, Y)$.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning for the uninitiated that $[X,Y]=\pi_0\mathrm{Map}(X,Y)$

Comment: @skd. Thank you. I just want to ask for a reference (or a proof) for your claim.

Comment: Proof: the collection of X for which that first map is an equivalence is closed under homotopy colimits and extensions and contains the n-sphere by definition. So it contains everything built from k spheres for k\ge n, as desired. The other claim follows from the first via a fiber sequence + the observation that \tau_{\ge n+1}Y=0.